Bad dream but not horror
I had a dream , I'm not gonna go into the details, but, I was with a family member, all the other people were random. All random.
At the end nothing bad happened to me or my family member but bad stuff did happen.
It was basically like a thriller movie and was interesting, so can I share it with my wife .
Again, not telling the details here , but some random people died due a scenario.

Questions about the interpretation of you dreams are off-topic. See Should dream interpretation questions be on-topic?.
